# rails_admin SQLite3::SQLException: no such column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

I use rails_admin. I have several tables, you can see all except one, when I try to look at it I get an error:

```
Showing /home/barmaley/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rails_admin-0.6.2/app/views/rails_admin/main/index.html.haml where line #135 raised: 

SQLite3 :: SQLException: no such column: headings.section_id: SELECT "headings". * FROM "headings" WHERE "headings". "Section_id" =?
```

its my section model

```
    class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :headings
  searchable do
  text :name
    end
end
```

and its my heading model

```
class Heading < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :section
  searchable do
    text :name
    text :address
    text :phone
  end
end
```

How can I resolve this error?

That's what I see when I try to view the table:

```
 - if @other_left_link ||= other_left && index_path(params.except('set').merge(params[:set].to_i != 1 ? {set: (params[:set].to_i - 1)} : {}))
%td.other.left= link_to "...", @other_left_link, class: 'pjax'
- properties.map{ |property| property.bind(:object, object) }.each do |property|
- value = property.pretty_value
%td{class: "#{property.css_class} #{property.type_css_class}", title: strip_tags(value.to_s)}= value
- if @other_right_link ||= other_right && index_path(params.merge(set: (params[:set].to_i + 1)))
%td.other.right= link_to "...", @other_right_link, class: 'pjax'
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "headings", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "address"
    t.integer  "phone"
    t.integer  "sec"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

create_table "sections", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

Comment: If you look at your db/schema.rb do you have a column called `section_id` in the headings table?  You need one otherwise `belongs_to :section` can't work.

Comment: just need to add this column?

Comment: Yes, "rails generate migration AddSectionIdToHeading section_id:integer" then "rake db:migrate"

Comment: Glad to hear it!  I'll post it as an answer, you can accept it, and I'll get much praise and admiration from friends and family. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your db/schema.rb you don't have a column called section_id in the headings table. You need one otherwise "belongs_to :section" can't work.

So you need to create that column.

```
rails generate migration AddSectionIdToHeading section_id:integer

rake db:migrate
```

cheers
Steve